# zxing barcode Android camera encountered when application open

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I have an Android app that launches the zxing barcode scanner through an 
Intent.My problem sometime  I get **"Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem.  You may need to restart the device".**

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: I would add that as a Bug on the Zxing bug-tracker...

Answer (score 2):

This means the device returned null from Camera.open() and it shouldn't ever do that. It's treated as a device bug.

I consistently getting this error only on Android 2.2 devices, event he device that have a front camera. The API for accessing a front camera only appeared in Android 2.3, and the previous Camera.open() API method may only return a rear-facing camera. So these return null. And it is a device bug, really, since they really need to be running Android 2.3 to let apps use a front camera.

Do test your app both front and back end camera. and check in which device you getting error repeatedly . Pl accept your answer is correct.